# Updating the Salescloud date field to Null using marketing cloud AMP script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sales-cloud

I am working marketing cloud AMPscript which updates the salescloud account object. I'm facing two issues here:

1. I couldn't retrieve the person account record type but my MC integration user has access to this field.
2. I couldn't empty the date field. I passed "NULL" for the date but I am getting an error. I am able to update with a valid date but I'm not able to empty the date field.

**This is the code I used:**

```
Set @result1 = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Account", "0016A00rtssssCfc", "FRN_Unsubscribe_Reason__pc", "Other", "Join_Date__pc", Null)
```

Answer (score 2):

We've noticed before that passing a space is required to null a field. Not 100% sure if it works for dates but worth a try ;)

```
Set @result1 = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Account", "0016A00rtssssCfc", "FRN_Unsubscribe_Reason__pc", "Other", "Join_Date__pc", " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not insert Null value in date fields so to over come you have to think out of the box -

```
%%[
SET @JoinDate = ""
IF Not Empty(@JoinDate) Then
    SET @Result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Account", "0016A00rtssssCfc", "FRN_Unsubscribe_Reason__pc", "Other", "Join_Date__pc", @JoinDate)
Else
    SET @Result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Account", "0016A00rtssssCfc", "FRN_Unsubscribe_Reason__pc", "Other")
EndIF
]%%
```

Comment: My requirement is i need to empty the date field.I have did this with SSJS in previous.

Comment: Did you try above code? if so what output did you received?

Comment: the else part in your code doesn't contain date field.I can update the date with valid values except Null

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old question, but I'm dropping an answer here in case someone needs it:

There is actually a way to set a field to null through UpdateSingleSalesforceObject using **fieldsToNull**. Here you go:

```
Set @result1 = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Account", "0016A00rtssssCfc", "FRN_Unsubscribe_Reason__pc", "Other", "fieldsToNull", "Join_Date__pc")
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is most possibly due to the fact that the field in Sales Cloud is set to "Required":**

Please check the field details in Service Cloud under *Setup -> App Setup -> Customize -> Accounts -> Fields* and clicking on your field "FRN_Unsubscribe_Reason__pc".

**If that isn't the problem, you could try using an empty string as the value to set:**

```
Set @result1 = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Account", "0016A00rtssssCfc", "FRN_Unsubscribe_Reason__pc", "Other", "Join_Date__pc", '')
```

Comment: I have checked it but its required only in some conditions.We have validation rules where date field should be empty under certain conditions.I was not able to pass null for any date fields.

Comment: Try using an empty string instead of null. Maybe that works.

Comment: I have tried empty string but it should be specified as "" .When i pass empty i get 500 internal server error.It expects null value.I tried updating in Salescloud with null value and it worked there through apex code.

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this. We apparently are running in the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in the following way:

if  empty(@snooze) then
set @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
'Contact',@subscriberkey,
"fieldsToNull", "Snoozed_Date__c"
)

else

set @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
'Contact',@subscriberkey,
'Snoozed_Date__c',@snooze
)

Well setting up the if and else condition where if empty(field_name) then it will send null value through fieldsToNull property of singlesalesforceUpdate function or in the ELSE part it will send the actual date value.